# Check if number is prime with Python thowing an exception

Tags: python, function, input

I have a python function that is supposed to take integer parameter and process it according to the logic in the function and print out whether the number is prime or not.
Am running my python file on Visual Studio 2019. Its throwing an exception on the parameter am passing into the function from the user.. here is what i got so far from the visual studio exception box `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

```
##Defining python function to check whether a certain number is prime or not
def check_Prime(o):
    isPrime=True
    for i in range(2,o):
        if(o%i==0):
          isPrime=False
    
    if(isPrime):
        print(o+" "+"is prime")
    else:
        print(o+" "+"is not prime")


prime=int(input("Enter the integer you would like to check for prime"))
check_Prime(prime)
```

Comment: `print(f"{o} is prime")`

Answer (score 1):

Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f'{o} is prime')
```

Your error points to concatenating `int` and `str`, which you cannot do.

Comment: Thanks for this, i didnt undertand it at first but now i figure its the print statements in the conditional structure